# Unresponsive for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a data set that contains different kinds of data as it is shown below

```
MMSI        Latitude    Longitude   Date        Time    Time (decimal)
277333444   59.8564     30.497      04-08-12    09:49   589
241025000   37.3462     24.8713     04-08-12    09:49   589
636012774   35.7931     28.7227     04-08-12    11:29   680
248681000   36.9327     27.3042     04-08-12    11:52   703
312847000   35.3429     28.5582     04-08-12    11:52   703
239737000   36.4827     27.9405     04-08-12    11:52   703
200         36.7672     34.6444     04-08-12    12:52   763
237071900   36.7778     24.578      04-08-12    12:52   763
```

and the data is imported from a csv file. In the sample data the time is sorted, but in the data the time is mixed. For the data, I want to compute the distance between two different points and get as a result the MMSIs involved as well as the times. I' ve written the following code, which does almost what I described.

```
fid = fopen('vessel-movements-2.csv');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %s %s %s %f', 'HeaderLines', 1,     'Delimiter', ',');
fclose(fid);
iscell(C);
M = cell2mat(C(:,1:5));

DateString = (C{1,7});
formatIn = 'dd-mm-yy';
P = datenum(DateString, formatIn);
M = horzcat(M,P);

Q = cell2mat(C(:,9));
M = horzcat(M,Q);

a = M(:,6);
b=unique( a );

c = M(:,1);
d = unique(c);

lat = M(:,2);
lon = M(:,3);

time = M(:,7);
TimeStamp = P+time;
M = horzcat(M,TimeStamp);

MM = sortrows(M,8);

all(M(:,8) == MM(:,8))

for i = 1:length(MM(:,8))
    t = MM(i,8);
    ind1 = i;
    length(ind1);
    lat1 = lat(ind1);
    lon1 = lon(ind1);

    while (t <= (MM(i,8)+5))
        for j = 2:length(d)
            ind2 = j;
            length(ind2);
            lat2 = lat(ind2);
            lon2 = lon(ind2);
            w = MM(j,8);            
        end

        dis = distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
        t = t+1;
    end


    if dis<=1

        contact = [ind1, ind2, t, w];
    end
  end
```

The indexes in the script are slightly different than what they should be from the shown data, but there are other columns in my data, which are not used in the loop, so for better visualization I left them out from the sample. It correctly computes the distance for the first time, but then in the outer loop the program seems to lag and run forever but without any results whatsoever. I tried the debugger but the result is the same. I cannot see the problem and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your `while` loop is modifying `t`, so it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: It seems that way in the sample data, but in the actual data, there are many  time  values that have difference of 1 or less than 5, so the `while` loop should modifying `t`

Comment: `t > (MM(i,8)+5);` does not change `t`

Comment: @vasouli as excaza says, inside the while loop you should have somehwre a line that reads `t=....` so you change the value of t.

Comment: I tried to increment `t` with `t=t+1;` and use it instead of  `t>(MM(i,8)+5);`, but that seems to have no effect at all. It is still stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Can you show us the version of the code in which you used `t=t+1`?

Comment: @TakeshiH. I edited the code in the original post, to see where I used `t=t+1`

Comment: Your code is making an awful lot of unnecessary effort... And I'm pretty sure it doesn't do what you think it does. Your whole inner loop over `j` seems to be in vain, its result only matters for the final value of `j=length(d)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a formatted comment. I just want to point out that your loops are very weird and dysfunctional. What you have in your current version, in effect does this:

```
for i = 1:length(MM(:,8)) %this should be size(MM,1)
    ind1 = i;
    lat1 = lat(ind1);
    lon1 = lon(ind1);

    ind2 = d;
    lat2 = lat(ind2);
    lon2 = lon(ind2);
    w = MM(d,8);
    t = MM(i,8)+5+1

    dis = distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);

    if dis<=1
        contact = [ind1, ind2, t, w];
    end
end
```

Comment: I understand that the code does what you say and not what I intend to do. But who do a write the `while` loop that its condition is that the time difference is 5 `t<=(MM(i+8)+5)` and for that time space computes the distance between all the possible pairs of MMSIs?

Comment: @vasouli Well, that would be a bit more complicated, and anyway another question altogether. Anyway, most loops could be spared. What I don't get is why you seem to get an infinite loop: it shouldn't behave that way.